# How can I let a node link to a URL (visNetwork, R)

Tags: r, visnetwork

```
#loading libraries
library(RedditExtractoR)
library(visNetwork)
library(dplyr)

#data
c <- reddit_content("https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/g5p6m6/mycrypto_integrates_defizap_to_earn_interest_on/")
v <- user_network(c)

#define nodes and edges
nodes <- v$nodes %>% rename("title"=.data$user)
edges <- v$edges %>% rename("width"=.data$weight) %>% mutate(arrows="to")

#create column with urls
nodes$url <- paste0("https://www.reddit.com/user/", nodes$title)

#network
visNetwork(nodes = nodes, edges = edges) #%>% visEvents(click = ???)
```

I'd like to make the url open in a new browserwindow when the user clicks on the node.
How do I make this happen? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Took me some time to try out stuff, this seems to works.
I used `selectNode` instead of `click` to avoid opening the URL when someone clicks in other areas of the canvas.

```
#network
visNetwork(nodes = nodes, edges = edges) %>% 
  visEvents(selectNode = 
  "function(params) {
    var nodeID = params.nodes[0];
    var url = this.body.nodes[nodeID].options.url;
    window.open(url, '_blank');
   }")
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a helpful answer [here](https://github.com/datastorm-open/visNetwork/issues/96) from bthieurmel. There it was suggested to make use of HTML embedding in the title.
Hence a possible solution could look like that:

```
nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3, title = c(
   '<a target="_blank" href = "http://www.google.com">Visit Google</a>',
   '<a target="_blank" href = "http://www.w3schools.com">VisitW3SC</a>',
   '<a target="_blank" href = "http://www.stackoverflow.com">Visit stackoverflow </a>'))

edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(1,3))

visNetwork(nodes, edges)
```